# Number of quadratic residues in the set of $k^2-4$'s

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

As we know, if $p$ is a prime, then $p$ has $\frac{p+1}{2}$ quadratic residues.
Consider the set $$A = \{k^2 - 4: k = 0, 1, \ldots, p-1\}$$
where $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$.

How many quadratic residues are there in $A$?

I tried with small primes such as $p = 7, 11, 23$ and I guess the answer is $\frac{p+1}{4}$, but I cannot prove it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried using quadratic reciprocity law?

Comment: You want to evaluate $\sum_k\sum_t\sum_ze^{2\pi i(k^2-4-z^2)t/p}$

Comment: Are you sure you did your calculations correctly?  The squares mod $7$ are $\{0,1,2,4\}$, and the elements of $A$ are $\{0, 3, 4, 6\}$.  Thus, there are only two quadratic residues in $A$.

Comment: @Aaron My mistake. I edited it.

Comment: @vidyarthi Could you give me some hints of using quadratic reciprocity law?

Comment: There was a series of exercises in Ireland-Rosen which led one to establish the number of quadratic residues followed by a quadratic residue, which is closely related (nearly equivalent I think).

Comment: @TienKhaPham Looking at your edit, $p+1/4$ will only be an integer when $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  Have you done for any primes congruent to 1 mod 4 (e.g., 5, 13, 17)?

Comment: @Aaron yes, I also noticed that point and edited it.

Comment: @TienKhaPham I think Gerry Myerson's comment is the best hint

Comment: May we have any estimation such as the number of quadratic residues $\le (p+1)/4$ or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

The congruence $k^2 - 4 \equiv x^2 \bmod p$ is solvable if and only if $(k,x)$ 
is an ${\mathbb F}_p$-rational point on the curve $K^2 - X^2 = 4$. Such curves are
easily parametrized. The simplest way of doing so is writing it in the form 
$(K-X)(K+X) = 4$ and setting $K-X = a$, $K + X = \frac{4}a$. Finally observe that $(k,x)$ and $(k,-x)$ correspond to the same residue.

Comment: Could you explain more for the "if and only if" condition, please?

Comment: It is an "if and only if" by definition.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, just an expansion on my comment.

$$\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi i(k^2-4-z^2)t/p}$$ is $p$ if $k^2-4\equiv z^2\bmod p$ and zero otherwise. So $$\sum_{z=0}^{p-1}\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi i(k^2-4-z^2)t/p}$$ is $2p$ if $k^2-4$ is a nonzero quadratic residue modulo $p$, it's $p$ if $k^2-4\equiv0\bmod p$ (that is, if $k\equiv\pm2\bmod p$), and otherwise it's zero. So $${1\over p}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\sum_{z=0}^{p-1}\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi i(k^2-4-z^2)t/p}$$ gives $2$ plus twice the number of values of $k$ such that $k^2-4$ is a nonzero quadratic residue.

When $t=0$, the sum on $k$ and $z$ is $p^2$, so we get 
$$p+{1\over p}\sum_{t=1}^{p-1}e^{-8\pi it/p}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi itk^2/p}\sum_{z=0}^{p-1}e^{-2\pi itz^2/p}$$ Now the sums on $k$ and $z$ are quadratic Gauss sums, whose values are well-known and easily found in texts and on websites. They depend on the residue of $p$ modulo $4$, and on whether $t$ and $-t$ are quadratic residues modulo $p$.